# Argument passed to __construct() expected to be SomeRepository, instance of EntityRepository instead

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I've defined my custom repositories according to the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html) and followed this [blog post](https://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-a-repository-instead-of-an-entity-manager/) to define them as a service. This normally works fine, except sometimes I get the exception:

> FatalThrowableError in SomeService.php line 20: Type error: Argument 3
>   passed to SomeService::__construct() must be an instance of
>   SomeRepository, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
>   given, called in var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line
>   7651

This happens quite a lot, and normally clearing the cache and the doctrine metadata cache solves it. But sometimes it doesn't.

```
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

I don't actually understand why this happens or how to fix it in the times that clearing the cache doesn't work. I know that this question (or derivative of it) has been asked a lot, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17228417/1393498), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24809566/1393498), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38542747/1393498), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28154975/1393498) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9248684/1393498). But none of those answers actually solves my problem, because as far as I can see I've defined everything correctly, also we have a bunch of other repositories defined exactly the same way and they all work fine.

```yaml
# services.yml
app.repository.some:
    class: AppBundle\Repository\SomeRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Some

app.some_service:
    class: AppBundle\Services\SomeService
    arguments:
        - "@app.repository.some"
```

```php
// Repository class
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class SomeRepository extends EntityRepository
{

}
```

```php
// Entity class
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\SomeRepository")
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Some
{
```

```php
// Service class
<?php

namespace  AppBundle\Services;

use AppBundle\Repository\SomeRepository;

class NotificationService
{
    /** @var SomeRepository */
    protected $someRepository;

    public function __construct(
        SomeRepository $someRepository,
    ) {
```

Is there some other cache that needs to be cleared or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the second @ORM\Entity and it will work just fine